# break the while loop after correct answer

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm a beginner developing a program with Python that is a mastermind game. all things work correctly but the only issue is after you guess a word correctly in a second or more chance you see you won the message, but the program asks you for another guess after that!
but I don't want this! I want to stop the program.

```py
import random

num = random.randint(1000, 10000)
print(num)
number = int(input('guess number :'))

if number == num:
    print('you are mastermind')
else:
    counter = 0

    while number != num:
        counter += 1
        count = 0
        num = str(num)
        number = str(number)
        print(num)
        correct = ['X'] * 4
        for i in range(0, 4):
            if num[i] == number[i]:
                count += 1
                correct[i] = num[i]
                print(correct[i], end=' ')
                if number == num:
                    counter += 1
                    print("You've become a Mastermind!")
                    print("It took you only", counter, "tries.")
                    break
            else:
                print('X', end=' ')
                continue
                print("\nNot quite the number. But you did get ", count, " digit(s) correct!")
        print('\n')
        number = int(input('Enter another number :'))


    if count == 0:
        print('None of the numbers in your input match.')
        num = int(input('Enter another number :'))
```

For example:

```
8389
guess number:8466
8389
8 X X X 

Enter another number:8389
8389
8 You've become a Mastermind!
It took you only 3 tries.


Enter another number:
```

Comment: Your `break` only breaks out of the nearest loop which is the `for` loop.

Comment: you can call exit(0) instead of break

Answer (score -1):

import random

num = random.randint(1000, 10000)
print(num)

number = int(input('Guess the number: '))

if number == num:
print('You are a Mastermind!')
else:
counter = 0

```
while number != num:
    counter += 1
    count = 0
    num_str = str(num)
    number_str = str(number)
    print(num_str)
    correct = ['X'] * 4

    for i in range(0, 4):
        if num_str[i] == number_str[i]:
            count += 1
            correct[i] = num_str[i]
            print(correct[i], end=' ')
            if number == num:
                counter += 1
                print("\nYou've become a Mastermind!")
                print("It took you only", counter, "tries.")
                break  # Add this line to exit the loop when the correct guess is made
        else:
            print('X', end=' ')
            continue
            print("\nNot quite the number. But you did get", count, "digit(s) correct!")
    
    print('\n')
    
    if count == 4:
        break  # Add this line to exit the loop when the correct guess is made

    number = int(input('Enter another number: '))

if count == 0:
    print('None of the numbers in your input match.')
    num = int(input('Enter another number: '))
```